# C++ Recurring Template pattern, including parent's nested template class

Tags: c++, crtp, incomplete-type

Please help, I need to unbundle a recurring dependency in the following (not actual, just illustrative) MSVC code from 2005. I'm compiling with g++ like this:

```
g++ -std=c++x -I. -o -Wall -Wextra -pedantic example example.cpp
```

**Code:**

```
template <typename R> struct AAA
{
    typedef R rep_t;

    static function(rep_t n, rep_t d) {return d;}
};

template <typename T> struct HELPER_CLASS
{
    //arithmetic operators:

    friend T operator/ (T const& lhs) {T res; res /=lhs; return res;}

    //... so on, also for comparison operators
}

template <typename  T=long> class BBB : public HELPER_CLASS< BBB<T> >
{

        typedef typename HELPER_CLASS< BBB<T> >::template AAA<T> P;
        typedef typename AAA<T>::rep_t rep_t;

    public:
        BBB& operator/=(BBB const& that) 
        {this->rep_=P::function(this->rep_, that.rep_); return *this;}

    private:
        rep_t rep_;
}
```

Compiling this, I get the following error:

> error: no class template named 'AAA' in 'struct HELPER_CLASS>'

When I declare AAA inside HELPER_CLASS so that it looks like this:

```
template <typename T> struct HELPER_CLASS
{
    //arithmetic operators:
    friend T operator/ (T const& lhs) 

    {T res; res /=lhs; return res;}
    //etc. for e.g. comparison operators

    template <typename R> struct AAA;
};
```

I'm left with this error:

> error: incomplete type HELPER_CLASS< BBB >::AAA' used in nested name specifier.

Is there a way to convince g++ to treat these things as loosely as MSVC?

How can I make sure the type will be defined once it's needed?
Thanks!

Comment: Indeed HELPER_CLASS< BBB<T> > does not have the template 'AAA'. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to use template AAA's member functions inside class BBB which inherits from HELPER_CLASS, parametrized by AAA. I aim to make this legacy MSVC code to work with g++, but I'm not at all savvy with templates (sigh)

Comment: Can you please make the example standalone-compilable?

Comment: Apparently I need to include more code as there exist also other 'loops' with other classes. If I just include these 3, the thing seems to get unbundled by declaring AAA inside HELPER_CLASS. I'll try to figure it out and update the question.

Comment: Indeed, my problems with the code were larger than this simple example. The example should work if you declare AAA inside HELPER_CLASS. The code had so many incompatibility issues with G++ that the original developer advised me to abandon it if I'm not a template jedi. So I'm writing it again from scratch. Thanks for the help.